# how to set the <ng-option> value in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<ng-select  [(ngModel)]="filtersMaster.granularity">
     <ng-option *ngFor="let opt of granularityJSONData" value="opt.val"> 
       {‌{opt.content}}  
     </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

where granularityJSONData contents are, after selecting an option from the dropdown, it does not hold the exact value of that particular content

EX - from drop down if i select   Recent 5 Min then value it shd hold is 5, but instead of that it contains opt.val, how to fix this ?

```
{
 "content" : "Recent 5 Min",
 "val" : "5"
 },
```

Comment: `[value]="opt.val"` you are binding a value, therefore you should use Angular's syntax

Comment: @swaroopbabaleshwar   why you don't use bindLabel and bindValue to make it easier????

Answer (score 3):

you can try this solution

add `[value]` in `ng-option` element

```
<ng-select  [(ngModel)]="filtersMaster.granularity"  >

     <ng-option *ngFor="let opt of granularityJSONData" [value]="opt.val"> {‌{ opt.content }  </ng-option>

</ng-select>
```